# What super cars in GTA Online can have the armoured window upgrade?

Tags: grand-theft-auto-online

While playing GTA Online, in one of the loading screens I got a message that some cars in Legendary Motorsport have the armoured window upgrade, but I couldn't find out which cars are, can you tell me?

I'm looking for anything that can be fast and also armoured so I can use on missions, tired of using Kirin all the time. Oh, and I don't want SUVs or Insurgent because they're not that fast.

Comment: I'm voting to close this as it asks for shopping advice on GTA Online.

Comment: @ardaozkal this is actually I doubt I have and couldn't find the answer anywhere else, why the urge to close it?

Comment: @ardaozkal Does it count if it's for ingame items?

Comment: @ardaozkal this ain't shopping advice, its a doubt. The only way I can find out about this right now is buying every car in the store and try it out, but I don't have all that money.

Comment: I'm not really sure what you're asking. Are you looking for a list of cars with a specific upgrade, or suggestions on which car to purchase?

Comment: @Wipqozn list of cars with specific upgrade

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In the [Executives and Other Criminals update](http://www.rockstargames.com/newswire/article/52545/gta-online-executives-and-other-criminals-now-available), Rockstar mention (emphasis mine):

> 10 new cars for sale, including a Turreted Limo and **6 new executive vehicles with armored variations**

The [wiki mentions the actual new cars](http://gta.wikia.com/wiki/GTA_Online:_Executives_and_Other_Criminals):

- Benefactor Schafter LWB
- Benefactor Schafter V12
- Enus Cognoscenti
- Enus Cognoscenti 55
- Gallivanter Baller LE
- Gallivanter Baller LE LWB

Note that the armoured versions aren't exactly the same as the Karuma: They are able to take a single RPG or sticky bomb. I believe the cars aren't as fast as the non-armoured versions.

Comment: That is exacly what I was looking for! Thank you for the links, list and additional info!